# what's the relation between volley and rest

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

Hello i know that volley is an http library used to send request and receive response but what's the relation between volley and rest , the word rest is not included in any of volley's documentation , can we say that volley is one of the manifestation of rest ? and how can volley and rest api can be related .
all informations are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST stands for Representational State Transfer which simply is a set of constraints based on HTTP. Web services that are compliant with REST, let the system that request data to retrieve and interact with textual representations of the service resources, through stateless operations.

In very basic words (and on the surface), you could say a web service is REST if you can interact with it over HTTP in a stateless way.

### How does a REST web service look like?

It's very common nowadays. An API server that lets you access resources through an URI, (like `/students`, `/students/1`, `/students/1/courses`, etc) and you consume and interact through a textual representation like JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Zarbag",
  "last_name": "Mohamed",
  "courses": ["math", "history", "science"]
}
```

#### Example

Your API service has these endpoints, all with `Content-Type: application/json`:

- `GET /students`: get a list of students
- `GET /students/1`: get details of the student with ID `1`
- `POST /students`: creates a new student. Expects a payload in the request body, with the student name, age, courses that will be taking, etc.

You can say this is a RESTful service.

### Volley

[Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) is just an Android library for making network requests through HTTP. It let's you request data from any web service that's accessible through the Internet, including those services which are REST-compliant, or "RESTful".

Comment: thanks for your fast answer !!!! :D , but how web services are compliant with rest

Comment: It's just as the text says: if you can interact with it in a stateless way, through textual representation (like JSON and URIs) you can say it's compliant with REST.

Comment: @Christopher Francisco  Can you describe what stateless means in this case?  And does a web service mean that the service is interacting with a website or does it just mean it is interacting with or through the Internet?